# java create raw packets tcp/icmp

Tags: java, c, tcp

i want to create raw packets in java like in c.

```
// Flags (8 bits)

  // FIN flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[0] = 0;

  // SYN flag (1 bit): set to 1
  tcp_flags[1] = 1;

  // RST flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[2] = 0;

  // PSH flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[3] = 0;

  // ACK flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[4] = 0;

  // URG flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[5] = 0;

  // ECE flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[6] = 0;

  // CWR flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[7] = 0;
```

this is a part from code in c and with it you can set the flags. I found some libraries like jnetpcap but as i can see there is not any function to manipulate them. 
Also, anyone know if i can execute c code from c?

Comment: Out of the box this is not possible with the Java API. You might need to use an 3rd party library (e.g. RockSaw, Jnetpcap, or similar)

Comment: Anyone know if you can execute C code from C? What?  You are **always** executing C code from C.  Have I missed something? Have you mispelled something?.  Please, edit.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle bit to understand what exactly are you trying to do (explain it in C, what do you use there, libnet, raw sockets...)? In Java, you can create raw TCP/IP sockets with the [java.net](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) package.

Second, jnetpcap (and any other library you find with pcap) is used for network caputring. If you read jnetpcap, says that it's a Java library to access the C library libpcap.

Last, the jnetpcap project also answers your question. Yes, you can run C code from within Java. Have a look at the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)

EDIT:
Sorry guys completely forgot that I used [jpcap](http://www.drdobbs.com/jpcap/199102239) for this kind of things about six years ago (damn time flys by).

```
import jpcap.*;
import jpcap.packet.*;

JpcapSender sender = JpcapSender.openDevice(NetworkInterface);
Packet packet = new TCPPacket(); //construct your TCP
packet.data = data; //what ever you want to send as payload
EthernetPacket ether = new EthernetPacket();
ether.frametype = (short) /*whatever you need*/
packet.datalink = ether;
sender.sendPacket(packet);
```

The code above is a very rough shortcut of what I did past then. But there is plenty of tutorials and examples out there to get started!

Comment: i want o create a project which will do ddos attacks like tcp syn. The subject said to create 3 types of attack

Comment: Do you have to use Java? I would suggest python with scapy. Using Java is pretty much like buying a Hummer to drive around in the city - the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: yes because i want to create afterall a android program to execute ddos attacks :P

Comment: Don't know if RockSaw runs on Android. I personally would either write it in C and use Android NDK (https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) or create my own TCP/IP implementation to customize it for my needs.

Comment: @Zonk, Sorry but I have been browsing the java.net package doc to search for a RawSocket class or something similar that allows you to get a raw socket.  Can you illustrate better your assert?

Comment: @LuisColorado Client Socket: `Socket clSkt = new Socket(server, port);` Then create the data stream to write and read, process whatever you want to process and close your socket at the end. [Java Socket Programming](http://www.buyya.com/java/Chapter13.pdf) or [Java Networking](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm)